# Manifolds with negative dimension – Definition, References

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds, string-theory, general-relativity

Does the concept of differential manifold with negative dimension make sense, in differential geometry?
If yes, how is it defined? Do you have any reference to recommend?

My problem was born in Einstein warped-product manifolds, i.e. to admit a type of metric, the fiber-manifold must have a negative dimension, but I do not know if that manifold makes sense in differential geometry, General Relativity or String Theory…

Thank you for any help

Comment: Do you know about $K$-theory? This makes sense of negative dimensional vector bundles. Another way of thinking about negative dimensional spaces is through the language of spectra. But I don't know how geometric you would consider that.

Comment: @Thomas Rot - Thank you! No, unfortunately I do not know the K-theory.. Could you tell me how these vector bundles are defined? Do you have some references?

Comment: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html

Comment: Look up "supermanifolds" and in particular an old review by Leites and the articles in the QFT for mathematicians book edited by Deligne et al.

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam - thank you very much for the advice I look for them right away

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Smooth manifolds of negative dimension are defined in derived geometry.

Recall that if A→M and B→M are two transversal submanifolds
of codimension a and b respectively,
then their intersection C is again a submanifold, of codimension a+b.

Derived geometry explains how to remove the transversality condition
and make sense out of a nontransversal intersection C
as a derived smooth manifold of codimension a+b.
In particular, dim C = dim M - a - b, and the latter number can be negative.

See Spivak, [Derived Smooth Manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5174).
[Simplicial approach to derived differential manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0033) by Borisov and Noel
simplifies Spivak's foundations considerably,
and Taroyan's [Equivalent models of derived stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.12699) simplifies them even further.

Comment: The nontransverse intersection example is very interesting, but it raises quite a few questions on its own regarding the concept of "negative manifold dimension". For instance, when does the relation to topological and Hausdorff dimensions break down, and how does that happen?

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro: The negative dimension is captured in the structure sheaf, not in the underlying topological space, so there is no connection to the topological or Hausdorff dimensions, since the latter do not depend on the structure sheaf.

Answer (score 5):

One place where negative dimensional manifolds appear naturally is complex cobordism $U^*$. Intuitively, elements of the abelian group $U^n(X)$ are represented by families of $(-n)$-dimensional manifolds varying over $X$.

Let us only define $U^*(X)$ for $X$ a finite-dimensional manifold, without boundary but not necessarily compact. Suppose $X$ is one such, of dimension $d$. Then, the abelian group $U^n(X)$ is zero for $n>d$ and can be nonzero for all $n\leqslant d$, also negative. It is generated by pairs $(\iota:M\hookrightarrow E,c)$ where $M$ is a $d-n$-manifold, $E$ is either the total space of a complex vector bundle over $X$ (for $n$ even) or $\mathbb R$ times such total space (for $n$ odd), and $c$ is a complex structure on the normal bundle of $\iota$ which is an embedding. Relations identify pairs that are cobordant. For details, see

*Quillen, D.*, [**Elementary proofs of some results of cobordism theory using Steenrod operations**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(71)90041-7), Adv. Math. 7, 29-56 (1971). [ZBL0214.50502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0214.50502).

For an element of $U^{-n}(X)$ represented by $(\iota,c)$ as above the composite of the projection of the bundle with $\iota$ gives a map $M\to X$ from a $d+n$-manifold $M$ to the $d$-manifold $X$ which can be thought of as a family of $n$-manifolds varying over $X$. This is intuitively understandable for $n\geqslant0$, but also keeps making sense for $n\leqslant0$ all the way until $n=-d$.